# Setting Up Google Analytics For a Website

Tags: google-analytics

I set up a small website and added Google Analytics. I poured through a lot documentation but can't find an answer to my question. I added the Global Tag and a Tag for each individual page. I am looking to see if I need to do both as I want to track site visits and what page they view. Do I actually need both (global tag and a tag for each page) and does the setup look correct? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-171082518-1"></script>
        <script>
             window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'UA-171082518-1');
        

            gtag('config', 'UA-171082518-1', {
            'page_title' : 'Resume',
            'page_path': '/#resume'
            });
            
            gtag('config', 'UA-171082518-1', {
            'page_title' : 'Contact',
            'page_path': '/#contact'
            });

            gtag('config', 'UA-171082518-1', {
            'page_title' : 'About',
            'page_path': '/#about'
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The global tag must be loaded on the page the first time it opens, if the others are pages that you send on the same a page (i.e. after scroll or click) you don't need to enter it again, but if you reload the page you have to reload the initial code.

Comment: The site I am tracking is robertritt.com. I want to track if an individual goes to for example the resume page. The GTM I set up tracks the downloads which seems to be working. So I only need the global analytic tag for the other tracking?                                                                        Thank you!

Comment: The site indicated does not respond, however every time the page is reloaded it must contain the global tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I misspelled the site name. It is roberttritt.com. The global tag is reloaded I think but I would like count the different sections. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is one page and I could not use the standard analytics set up I added the following to allow me to track what section of the site a user visits.

/*======== Gtag Per Section Setup ========*/
$('.nav-menu a').on('click', function() {

```
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.hasClass('activeGt')) {
        return;
    }
    $('.nav-menu a').removeClass('activeGt');

    $this.addClass('activeGt');

    var page_href = $this.attr('href');
    var page_title = page_href.replace('#', '');

    page_title = page_title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + page_title.slice(1) + '-Section';

    var path = (window.location.href).replace(window.location.origin, '').toLowerCase();

    path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf('#'));
    path = path + page_href;
    
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-171082519-1', {
        'anonymize_ip': true, // for GDPR
        'page_title' : page_title,
        'page_path': path
    });
});
```